# Bootstrap center content horizontaly and push/pull content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hnfdf9y1/1/

It two rows with 2 cells each that contain text that is centered vertically.

I need to center the white circle with the text horizontaly so it's centered in it's block

This is espically important when the white circle is above the text and the blocks are 100%.

I also need to push or pull the second row so when it breaks to 100% the white circle is above the text and not above like it is now.

```
        <div class="container">

          <div class="row">
              <div class="block clearfix">

                  <div class="col-sm-4  col-lg-3 col">
                      <div class="circle">
                          <p class="extract extract_percent">50%</p>
                          <p class="extract extract_fact">Some Text</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-sm-8  col-lg-9 col">
                      <div class="text">
                         <p class="fact">More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text </p>
                      </div>    
                  </div>


                  <div class="col-sm-8  col-lg-9 col">
                      <div class="text">
                         <p class="fact">More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text </p>
                      </div>    
                  </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4  col-lg-3 col">


        body{
            background: blue;
        }

        .col{
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        .block{
            display: table;
            height: 120px;
        }

        .block .circle{
            background: white;
            border-radius: 140px;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            height: 140px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 140px;
        }
        .extract{
          color: $at-blue-dark;
          margin: 0;
        }

        .extract_percent{
          font-size: 2em;
          font-weight: bold;
        }

        .extract_fact{
          font-size: 1.1em;
        }

        .text{
          display: table-cell;
          vertical-align: middle;
          height: 140px;
        }

        .fact{
            color: white;
        }
```

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/hnfdf9y1/14/

Comment: Perfect thanks, any idea about push/pull

Answer (score 1):

Wrapp cirle class with new element class CSS class

```
.center-circle {
 display:table;
}

<div class="center-circle">
    <div class="circle">
                  <p class="extract extract_percent">50%</p>
                  <p class="extract extract_fact">Some Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your class `.block .circle` to:

```
.block .circle {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 140px;
    /*display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;*/
    height: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And add `padding-top: 35px;` to `.extract_percent` or your desired padding:

```
.extract_percent{
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 35px;
}
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hnfdf9y1/14/)

**Update**

To change the position on 100% width in your example you have to do the following:

Change the order of the last two `.col` div's. Add `.col-sm-push-8` to the first and `.col-sm-pull-4` to the last. Like this:

```
          <div class="col-sm-4  col-lg-3 col col-sm-push-8 col-lg-push-9">
          <div class="circle">
              <p class="extract extract_percent">50%</p>
              <p class="extract extract_fact">Some Text</p>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-8  col-lg-9 col col-sm-pull-4 col-lg-pull-3">
          <div class="text">
             <p class="fact">More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text </p>
          </div>    
      </div>
```

You have to change the order of the div's, because bootstrap is **mobile first**, therefore you have to make your "small" layout first with the html and the "wide" layout is controlled by the utility classes, like `.col-xx-push-xx`.

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hnfdf9y1/16/)

Comment: Thanks for your help Sebsemillia - The code works at small sizes but if you make the window larger the bottom row is out of place and moves over to the left

Comment: Ah sorry, I updated my code. You have to add the utility classes for the `col-lg-xx` as well.. (http://jsfiddle.net/hnfdf9y1/17/)